# c# value sent to Func not peristant, c# IIFE equivalent

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, func, iife

This loop is executed

```
CoordPosition = new Func<string, int>[3];
for (int i = 0; i < CoordPosition.Length; i++)
{
     CoordPosition[i] = (x => CapStringNumber(x, i));
}
```

When the method CapStringNumber is later executed by the funcs its second parameter has the value 3 for the entire array. I want it to be 0, 1, 2.

The following works:

```
CoordPosition = new Func<string, int>[3];
for (int i = 0; i < CoordPosition.Length; i++)
{
     var localVariable = i; 
     CoordPosition[i] = (x => CapStringNumber(x, localVariable));
}
```

What is the proper way to achieve the effect I want? Making that localVariable seems a bit un-maintainable. I don't know javaScript but i'm told that 'IIFE' is a relevant javaScript term for this.

Comment: Your second sample is a proper way.  _Making that localVariable seems a bit un-maintainable_ - in which way it is unmaintainable?

Comment: I recommend [this](http://www.codethinked.com/c-closures-explained) and [this](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) to find out more about Closures.

Comment: I meant unmaintainable in the way that it looks like a unnecessary variable, which could be refactored by mistake. Coupled with a comment it would be safer ofcourse

Comment: Copying the variable inside your closure seems the way to go. [Captured variable in a loop in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp) (Jon Skeet surely knows best!).

Comment: FYI you can omit the `(...)`: ` = x => CapStringNumber(...)`;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Captured variable in a loop in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp)

Comment: And no, IIFE is totally different (you can see what it is if you look at the description of the tag)